# Previous date for category in data frame into next row of the same category

Tags: r

X represents a vector of names of participants in a sporting event. Y represents the amount of points that the participant scored. The output format will be used for predictive analytics, such as using the  scores from y3 and y2 to predict y1.

Starting with this data frame:

```
    date1       x   y1
1   2008-10-01  B   78
2   2008-10-01  A   33
3   2008-10-15  A   89
4   2008-10-22  B   43
5   2008-10-22  C   36
6   2008-10-23  A   23
7   2008-11-01  C   66
```

I need a low overhead solution to produce the following data frame:

```
      date1     x   y1    date2     y2    date3     y3
1   2008-10-01  B   78      NA      NA
2   2008-10-01  A   33      NA      NA
3   2008-10-15  A   89  2008-10-01  33      NA
4   2008-10-22  B   43  2008-10-01  78      NA
5   2008-10-22  C   36      NA      NA
6   2008-10-23  A   23  2008-10-15  89  2008-10-01  33
7   2008-11-01  C   66  2008-10-22  36      NA
```

Here is sample data:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/ACEO/sample.Rds

https://s3.amazonaws.com/ACEO/result.Rds

Comment: It would help if you described what you're trying to do and why you need this format.

Comment: I added a description as an intro to the question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think having your data in this format will help your analysis.

Comment: @SeñorO This is exactly what I need to do the analysis that I am doing.

Comment: Then you're not using R the best way possible

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the desired output using `dplyr` (assuming that you dont actually want blanks in parts of `date3` and `y3`)

```
require(dplyr)

dat %.%                      #assuming your data.frame is called `dat`
  group_by(x) %.%
  mutate(date2 = lag(date1, 1),
         y2 = lag(y1, 1),
         date3 = lag(date1,2),
         y3 = lag(y1,2))

#       date1 x y1      date2 y2      date3 y3
#1 2008-10-01 B 78         NA NA         NA NA
#2 2008-10-01 A 33         NA NA         NA NA
#3 2008-10-15 A 89 2008-10-01 33         NA NA
#4 2008-10-22 B 43 2008-10-01 78         NA NA
#5 2008-10-22 C 36         NA NA         NA NA
#6 2008-10-23 A 23 2008-10-15 89 2008-10-01 33
#7 2008-11-01 C 66 2008-10-22 36         NA NA
```

Comment: Worked very well. On 750,000 rows.                              user  system elapsed 
  16.63    0.04   16.69